# rational Hodge structure of spectral curve and Prym variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hodge-theory, prym-varieties

I have a problem about rational Hodge structure of spectral curves and Prym varieties.
I want to prove the following,

> Let $X$ be smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathscr{M}$ be moduli space of semistable Higgs bundle and $H:\mathscr{M}\rightarrow \bigoplus H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes i})$ be the Hitchin map.
> $X_s$ is the spectral curve associated to $s \in \bigoplus H^0(X, K_X^{\otimes i})$, and
> $P_s$ is the Prym variety for the covering $X_s \rightarrow X$
> There is an isomorphism of rational Hodge structure $H^1(X_s)\cong H^1(X)\bigoplus H^1(P_s)$.

I could find no reference. Any help or comment will do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spectral curves, it is true for any covering $C\rightarrow B$, since the Prym variety is the kernel of the surjective map $JC\rightarrow JB$.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand yet, how can I deduce exact sequence $0\rightarrow H^1(Prym)\rightarrow H^1(C)\rightarrow H^1(B)\rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: What you write is actually for $H_1$, not $H^1$. And it follows directly from the  exact sequence $0\rightarrow \operatorname{Prym}\rightarrow JC\rightarrow JB\rightarrow 0$.